# Replacing spaces with underscores with php

Tags: php, replace

This is a one  very newbie question but i  just  can't figure  out  where the problem is
so please bear  with me...

Here's what i am trying to achieve --> `$new = 'OMG_This_Is_A_One_Stupid_Error';`

here's  what  i am getting from this code -->`$new = 'OMG This Is A One Stupid_Error';`

```
<?php 
    $find = 'OMG This Is A One Stupid Error'; //just an example
    $offset = 0;
    $search = ' ';
    $length = strlen($search);
    $replace = '_';
    while($substring = strpos($find, $search,$offset))
    {
        $new =  substr_replace($find, $replace,$substring,$length);
        $offset = $substring + $search_length;
    }   
    echo $new;
?>
```

Comment: You might want to look up http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: http://php.net/str-replace Or in other words: You are not only reinventing the wheel, but also the fire and the use of stones to kill animals for food ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/str_replace) function:

```
<?php
    $old = 'OMG_This_Is_A_One_Stupid_Error';
    $new = str_replace(' ', '_', $old);
    echo $old; // will output OMG This Is A One Stupid error
?>
```

Reverse the parameters to obtain the reverse effect

```
<?php
    $old = 'OMG This Is A One Stupid_Error';
    $new = str_replace('_', ' ', $old);
    echo $old; // will output OMG_This_Is_A_One_Stupid error
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to introduce you to [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=str_replace)

```
$var = str_replace(' ', '_', $var);
```

Comment: the order of the parameters is wrong: "mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] ) "

Answer (score 0):

You could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

If you just want your source string to have underscores replaced with spaces use this:

```
$source = 'OMG This Is A One Stupid Error'; //just an example

// $new is: OMG_This_Is_A_One_Stupid_Error
$new = str_replace(' ', '_', $source);
```

If the source string is a substring of a larger string you can do this:

```
$source     = 'This is a question for SO. '
            . 'OMG This Is A One Stupid Error';
$to_replace = 'OMG This Is A One Stupid Error';
$target     = str_replace(' ', '_', $to_replace);

// Finally replace the target string
$new = str_replace($to_replace, $target, $source)

// $new is: This is a question for SO. OMG_This_Is_A_One_Stupid_Error
```